# Polar coordinate differentials

Tags: polar-coordinates, transformation, differential

We all know that when switching to polar coordinates we have:
$$
x = r\cos\theta,\qquad y = r\sin\theta
$$
and either by a geometric argument or using the Jacobian we have:
$$
dx\,dy = r\,dr\,d\theta
$$
But also, using the definition of differential:
$$dx = x_r\,dr + x_\theta \,d\theta = \cos\theta\,dr - r\sin\theta \,d\theta$$

and
$$dy = y_r\,dr + y_\theta \,d\theta= \sin\theta \,dr + r\cos\theta \,d\theta$$

giving,

\begin{align}
dx\,dy & = (\cos\theta \,dr - r\sin\theta \,d\theta)(\sin\theta \,dr + r\cos\theta \,d\theta) \\
&= \sin\theta \cos\theta \,dr\,dr + r\cos^2\theta \,dr\,d\theta - r\sin^2\theta \,dr\,d\theta - r^2\sin\theta \cos\theta \,d\theta \,d\theta  \tag{*}
\end{align}

I do not understand how this ends up being the same as $r\,dr\,d\theta$.

I have found two separate threads with answers I find unsatisfactory:

1. [dA in polar coordinates using total differentials](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1456206/da-in-polar-coordinates-using-total-differentials?noredirect=1&lq=1)
2. [Explain $\iint \mathrm dx\,\mathrm dy = \iint r \,\mathrm \,d\alpha\,\mathrm dr$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/37044/explain-iint-mathrm-dx-mathrm-dy-iint-r-mathrm-d-alpha-mathrm-dr)

In (1) the there is a claim that $dx$ and $dy$ are vectors. Well, so what? That is not strictly a requirement, and one still ends up with a problematic $\cos^2\theta - \sin^2\theta$ term.

In (2) the third answer explains that in the context of differential forms and wedge products that $dx\land dx = dr \land dr = 0$ and $dx\land dy = -dy \land dx$ and if one omits the $\land$ symbols and looks the other way then magically we do get $dx\,dy = r\,dr\,d\theta$.

This thread goes into more detail on the use of the wedge product:

[Transforming differentials to polar coordinates](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2687333/transforming-differentials-to-polar-coordinates)

I feel uneasy with all this. Are we saying that, in fact, all the time that we have been writing things like $dx\,dy$ in undergrad we always actually meant $dx\land dy$ without knowing it? If that is true, why are we not required to change $dx\,dy$ to $-dy\,dx$ when we change the order of integration in double integrals?

Is there a way to deduce $(*) = r\,dr\,d\theta$ without resorting to weird exterior products?